# no me carga el template en django 1.11.8

Tags: html5, django, djangorestframework

Buenos dias para todos, el fin de este mensaje es para si ud me pueden ayudar a encontrar el error ya que no me carga un template sacando el error 404:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/manager/panel/noticia/1/
Raised by:  manager.views.NoticiaUpdateView

No se encontró ningún noticia coincidente con la consulta
```

este es el template admin_base:

```
<li class="mm-dropdown">
                    <a href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-check-square"></i><span class="mm-text">Noticias</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='{% if request.path == "/manager/panel/noticia/1/" %}active{% endif %}'>
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'gestionar-noticia-actual' 1 %}"><span class="mm-text">Actualizar</span></a>
                        </li>
```

el extends:

```
{% extends 'admin_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <!-- 5. $CONTENT ===================================================================================-->
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="panel-title">GESTIONAR NOTICIA ACTUAL</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Publicar" class="btn btn-success" />
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
</div> <!-- / #content-wrapper -->
{% endblock %}
```

el views:

```
> class NoticiaUpdateView(UpdateView):
>     template_name = "noticias/add.html"
>     form_class = NoticiaForm
>     model = Noticia
>     success_url = '/manager/panel/noticia/1/'
```

y el urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import (
    LoginView, ObituarioAddView, ObituarioListView, 
    ObituarioUpdateView, ObituarioHistoricoListView,
    NoticiaUpdateView, EventoListView, EventoAddView, EventoUpdateView,
    EventoHistoricoListView, logout_view, procesarc_csv, 
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='panel'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^procesar_csv/$', procesarc_csv, name='procesar_csv'),
    url(r'^panel/obituarios/$', ObituarioListView.as_view(), name='gestionar-obituarios'),
    url(r'^panel/obituario/agregar/$', ObituarioAddView.as_view(), name='agregar-obituario'),
    url(r'^panel/obituario/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ObituarioUpdateView.as_view(), name='editar-obituario'),
    url(r'^panel/obituarios/historico/$', ObituarioHistoricoListView.as_view(), name='gestionar-obituarios-historicos'),
    url(r'^panel/noticia/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NoticiaUpdateView.as_view(), name='gestionar-noticia-actual'),
    url(r'^panel/eventos/$', EventoListView.as_view(), name='gestionar-eventos'),
    url(r'^panel/eventos/agregar/$', EventoAddView.as_view(), name='agregar-evento'),
    url(r'^panel/evento/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EventoUpdateView.as_view(), name='editar-evento'),
    url(r'^panel/eventos/historico/$', EventoHistoricoListView.as_view(), name='gestionar-eventos-historicos'),
]
```

gracias por la atencion y colaboracion

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra una noticia con el `id=1` intenta con otro id o verifica que tengas en la base de datos una noticia con ese id

Comment: Necesito más detalles del error si pones un pantallazo del error seria de mucha ayuda, también quisiera saber  la estructura de tu proyecto (carpetas y archivos)

Comment: No es un problema de template. Como dijo @GermanAlzate, estás buscando una noticia que no existe, por eso te muestra el error 404.